# Reversing a user input digit using methods

Tags: java, methods, user-input, reverse, digit

I want to take any user input integer between 1 and 9999 and return that number with its digits reversed. The problem with my code is it's returning the sum of the entered integer and I have no idea how to fix it. This is the code that that I came up with so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Reverse{
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 9999: ");
        int user = input.nextInt();

        if(user>1 && user<9999){
            System.out.println("The number with its digits reversed is : " + reverseDigit(user));

        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }   

    }

    public static int reverseDigit(int num){

        return (num%10 + (num%100)/10 + (num%1000)/100 + num/1000); //This is the problem

    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you take the input as a string, reverse it and then convert it into an integer?

Comment: Hint: `num % 10 * 1000` moves the last digit to the first position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace :

```
return (num%10 + (num%100)/10 + (num%1000)/100 + num/1000);
```

with:

return ((num%10)*1000 + ((num%100)/10 )*100+ ((num%1000)/100)*10 + num/1000);

The reason that the first was wrong is because you get:

```
last digit:num%10
third digit:num%100)/10
second digit:(num%1000)/100
first digit:num/1000
```

so you was just adding all the digits before

**But the Above works only for numbers from 1000-9999 .So you could replace the reverseDigit method with this simple method that works for every number:**

```
 public static int reverseDigit(int num){
        int reverse=0;
        while( num != 0 )
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + num%10;
            num = num/10;
        }
        return reverse;
    }
```

Comment: Your solution only works from 1000-9999. Try it with 3 or less digits. 23->3200

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. But I don't understand the logic here. Whats the reason you multiplied the digits by 1000, 100 and 10?

Comment: because for example with the number 9875 you ware taking the digits 9,8,7,5 and returning 5+7+8+9 =29 but you need to return: 5000+700+80+9=5789 which is the number you want, so that's why you need to multiply before return the number. You multiply  in order to construct the right number!!

Comment: Ohh okay, I understand the logic now. Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: Oh my apologies @coder. I wasn't aware that there was a function like that. I've edited my post and ticked your answer correct. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @Vishal, glad to help!!

Answer (score 2):

First, convert the number into a string then reverse the string and reconvert it into a number.

```
public static int reverseDigit(int num)
{
  String str;
  str = String.valueOf(num);
  str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
  return (Integer.parseInt(str));
}
```

Comment: We achieved the goal but the logic is not fit

Comment: This does work and is very readable and works for any number length, so upvoted. You ought to check for negative numbers though. But it will not be fast. An excellent solution will be numeric.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int reverseDigit(int num) {
    int result = 0;
    while(num != 0 ) {
        result *=10;
        int temp = num % 10;
        result += temp;
        num /=10;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it using `int` (although `String` would be better).

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Reversed: " + 1234 + " = " + reverseDigits(1234, 4));
}

public static int reverseDigits(int num, int digits) {
    int reversed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
        reversed *= 10;
        reversed += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return reversed;

}
```